# I get error process /bin/sh -c did not complete successfully when building docker on arm

Tags: docker, buildx

I need my docker to be build for arm and the packages are only for arm that i want to include.
When i run my docker on an arm machine or on an amd64 machine with the linux/arm64 flag i get the following error: "Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c /deps/install_deps.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100"
[here on github](https://github.com/zelda1link3/frigateRockchip/actions/runs/4863110980/jobs/8670340324)
I also get this if i do RUN ls -l /deps/ but then the error is:
"Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ls -l /deps/" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100"

It is not emulation because it also happens on native arm64 machines.

The complete docker file to reproduce this issue is:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 arm64v8/debian:11-slim  AS deps

RUN ls /
```

I have tried lots of things to solve this but i have no idee anymore

Comment: Please make sure to put all information here and don't crosslink. What's your error message? What does your dockerfile look like and so on. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't think the docker file will add anything and the error was already in here but i edditted so it would maybe be easier to find.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i tried to google but i just don't know where this comes from and i have no idea how to get started on solving this. I just don't understand why this only happens if i run on arm64 and not on amd64.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the platform you are specifying for the image you are trying to pull. You are facing this issue because the `arm64v8/debian:11-slim` image doest not have an image for `linux/arm64` architecture. The `arm64v8` images are for the Apple silicon hosts i.e. currently M1 and M2 based macs

You can solve this problem by using the following pull statement in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 debian:11-slim AS deps

RUN ls /
```

This would fix the issue as the debian dockerhub repository has all the arch needed for [debian:11-slim](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/tags?page=1&name=11-slim).

Comment: I had that previously and the same error this is one of the things I tried to fix it but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: can you try removing the platform argument as docker will take care of pulling the image for the relevant arch. So, the first line would be: FROM debian:11-slim AS deps